# How to return a value from async for JQuery Validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, return

Using the async module for JS, I need to retrieve values from two functions running in parallel and then use them on a callback that returns a final true/false value.

There seems to be a problem with the async scope, since I can't retrieve the return value from the callback. Any ideas on how to do this?

This is the code. It's basically a validator for received values:

```
$.validator.addMethod('verifySystem', function (value, element) {
    var data = value.split(':');
    var respuesta;
    async.series([
        function (callback) {
            if( data.length === 3){
                // is this format the correct one?
                if ((data[1] == 'testi' || data[1] == 'tes') && data[2].length == 6 && data[0].length == 7){
                    callback(null, 'ok');
                } else {
                    callback('Error in format',null);
                }
            } else {
                callback('Error in format', null);
            }
        },
        function (callback) {
            // does the document exist?
            var ajaxverify = function() {
                return $.ajax({
                url: 'db_test/' + value
                });
            };

            ajaxverify()
            .done(function(result) {
                 callback(null, 'ok');
            })
            .fail(function(error) {
                 callback('not_found', null);
            });
        }
    ],
    function (errors, results) {
        if (errors){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
}, "error message");
```